# Validation a accessToken in NESTJS

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js

Im having some issues with validation a jwt in nestjs. Alot of documentation and tutorials show how to create token etc. I just want to validate it and protect graphql resolvers.

In my jwt.strategy.ts i have this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: 'xxxxx',
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: 'urn:microsoft:userinfo',
      issuer: 'xxxxx',
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  validate(payload: unknown): unknown {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

And in my authz module i have:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' })],
  providers: [JwtStrategy],
  exports: [PassportModule],
})
export class AuthzModule {}
```

In my resolvers i use the UseGuards decorator:

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
```

All this should work, but i get an error:
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logIn')**

I dont want to do any login, just validate the token.

ANy tips on this? Have tried google, been at it for hours. Thanks!